# Best way to delete documents in marklogic which are having multiple version

Tags: xquery, marklogic

We had documents in database which are having multiple versions. For ex 
Documents URI are like below :-

```
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-2
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-3
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-4
.
.
.
.
.
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-998
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-999
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-1000
```

We need to find the count of all the documents like this and then delete all the versions of document which are above ".version-20".

For example

```
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-19 --> NOT DELETE
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-20 --> NOT DELETE 
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-21 --> TO BE DELETED
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-22 --> TO BE DELETED
.
.
.
.
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-999 --> TO BE DELETED
/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-1000 --> TO BE DELETED
```

we had multiple directories where multiple documents are present. 
As of now, we are counting documents like below

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
fn:count(fn:doc("/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-*"))
```

What is the best way to delete documents like this ?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to preserve the most recent versions, being the last numbers? It would be easier to work with a timestamp, and do a cts:uris with a date range query. Would that be an option?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We used 
`xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
for $i in 1 to 980 
return 
xdmp:document-delete('/PremierLeague/Manutd/players.xml-version-*'||$i||)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the uri lexicon and use one of the 'uris' or 'directory' functions like cts:uris, not fn:doc -- fn:doc 'opens' the document and returns the document node, not the uri.
You dont want to do that when your deleting documents.

Be careful with the chosen pattern of versions and the requirements -- as-stated you may end up deleting *all* versions, and documents which happen to have the substring "-version" in them before being versioned would be mis-matched (with your sample code).

Consider the Document Library Services which manages versions of documents including retention policies.